# reading build artifacts in a Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to write a Jenkins plugin that reads a JSON file generated by my build and displays a summary of its data on the respective build page. I've followed the example of other plugins and have custom classes that extend `Action`, `BuildStepDescriptor<Publisher>`, and `Recorder`, and can successfully display custom text on the build page, but how do I access the build artifact?

In my custom `Action` class, the overriden `perform()` method receives a `final AbstractBuild<?, ?> build` argument, which has a handy `getRootDir()` method, but this seems to return the path of the directory containing all of the *archived* build files (i.e. those that were explicitly saved), and it's not the path of the actual build working directory.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found that `AbstractBuild` also has a `getWorkspace()` method, which let me retrieve my desired file like so: `build.getWorkspace().child("report.json")`. Unsure whether this is a fullproof solution, though.